# How to change log level from number to log name using ougai logger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I am using [ougai](https://github.com/tilfin/ougai) logger to enable custom logging in Ruby on Rails application. When I try to print the below log, it prints "level" in numbers. Instead, I want it in the log level itself.

```
logger.info('Information!')

{"name":"main","hostname":"mint","pid":14607,"level":30,"time":"2016-10-16T22:26:48.835+09:00","v":0,"msg":"Information!"}
```

Expected result

```
logger.info('Information!')

{"name":"main","hostname":"mint","pid":14607,"level":"Info","time":"2016-10-16T22:26:48.835+09:00","v":0,"msg":"Information!"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked a while ago, but for anyone else who lands here with the same question...

The way I've addressed this is to make a customer formatter:

```
class LogLevelLoggerFormatter < Ougai::Formatters::Bunyan
  # override the to_level method to just return the string
  # instead of converting it to an integer
  # see .../gems/ougai-1.5.8/lib/ougai/formatters/bunyan.rb
  def to_level(severity)
    severity
  end
end
```

Then, in the config/environment file(s):

```
  require 'log_level_logger_formatter'
  require 'ougai'

  Cube::Application.configure do
    config.logger = Ougai::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    config.logger.formatter = LogLevelLoggerFormatter.new
    # ... other config
  end
```

This issue was the *"inspiration"* for this approach: https://github.com/tilfin/ougai/issues/99